# Package Verification Keys for CentOS SCL RPMs

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6, software-collections

This is probably a silly question, but...

Our security folks prefer that we enable GPG-checking for all RPMs to be installed. We've recently started using packages from the CentOS.Org packaging of Software Collections. When I try to install these, `yum` helpfully yells at me about not having verifiable keys. When I look at the CentOS.Org site's page concerning GPG keys, the SCL packages are shown as having a key/fingerprint, but, unlike the other keys listed on that page, there's no download link.

Is the GPG verification key simply not available or am I simply missing something blindingly obvious? At any rate, any help in tracking down a checking-key that I can install to my systems would be of great assistance.

Comment: It should be the same key as everything else from CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each SIG has its own key, and the public key is distributed in the -release package in the CentOS Extras repository. The Extras repo packages are then signed by the main "CentOS 7 Signing Key" from [CentOS GPG Keys](https://www.centos.org/keys/).

The key for the SCLo SIG (special interest group) [is missing](https://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=12844) from the main CentOS keys list, but it is still available in the release package.

Run `yum install centos-release-scl` (from Extras) to automatically configure the repository and public key.

Or if you want a copy of the public key itself, you can extract and verify it from the centos-release-scl package by hand:

1. Download the [centos-release-scl RPM](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm) directly, or use `yumdownloader centos-release-scl` (from yum-utils).
2. Verify the file against the regular CentOS key:

   ```
   $ rpm -K centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm
   centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm: rsa sha1 (md5) pgp md5 OK
   ```
3. Extract the key from the RPM into `SCLo.pub`:

   ```
   $ rpm2cpio centos-release-scl-2-2.el7.centos.noarch.rpm | cpio -i --to-stdout ./etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-SCLo > SCLo.pub
   ```

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I'd ended up doing.